# stored procedure showing first result set columns every time in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a stored procedure like this:

```
if(@sub_sheetpart= 'c') 
    begin   
      select a,b,c from table1        
    end
if(@sub_sheetpart= 'd')    
    begin       
       select a,b,c,d,e,f from table2   
    end
```

Only one resultset will be returned at a time from the stored procedure.

The problem is in the SSRS dataset - it only shows the first resultset's columns every time, that is column `a,b,c`, even if I am going to call the later part of the store procedure (`@sub_sheetpart= 'd'`).

Answer (score 3):

SSRS will only consider one set of results when generating the list of fields in a DataSet.

You can work around this problem to make sure whatever is run you get the same fields like this:

```
if(@sub_sheetpart= 'c')
begin

  select a
    , b
    , c
    , d = null
    , e = null
    , f = null
  from table1

end
if(@sub_sheetpart= 'd')
begin

  select a
    , b
    , c
    , d
    , e
    , f
  from table2

end
```

Recreate the DataSet based on the above - it will now have the six expected fields.

Another option would be to flip the order of the `if`/`else` so the second query is on the first `if` section.

You could even just manually add the fields into the DataSet in the DataSet designer.

Comment: sorry but actually there are two diffrent tables from which data is fatched.

Comment: All of the advice still applies - by adding the `NULL` columns both queries return exactly the same interface so it doesn't matter which one SSRS looks at when generating the DataSet definition. The other two options still apply as well.

Comment: Ian , procedure has many if-else blocks and all are returning different columns from different tables,Now in ssrs i am using different datasets to call same procedure every time, but the parameters are different. problem is that every time in dataset's  fields it shows the columns returned by procedure's first if-else block  even if i am calling the procedure with parameters to select data from last if-else block, i have to manually change these fields in dataset every time.

Answer (score 1):

There is one more work around, although it is not proper but you can get the desired result.
You can make a temporary table and then insert null after every `if` statement.

For Example:

```
create table #temp
(
id int
)

if(@sub_sheetpart= 'c')
begin

insert #temp(
id
)
select null
  select a
    , b
    , c
   from table1

end
if(@sub_sheetpart= 'd')
begin
insert #temp(
id
)
select null

  select  
      e
    , f
  from table2

end
```